# $(class).click() not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

Beginner here. I made some simple code that added a class to certain images when I click a button. When I click an image with that class, I want to remove the class from all elements that have it. However, I can't seem to remove the class. Here's all the relevant HTML/CSS:

```
.us{
    border-style:solid;
    border-color:#ff0000;
    }

...

<button id="us_select"> select American films </button><br>
<!--When I click this button, all images of American films will have red borders by 
adding the "us" class--> 

<img id="sutter" src="sutter.png" alt="sutter">
<img id="theo" src="her.png" alt="theo">
<img id="holly" src="holly.png" alt="holly">
<img id="matsu" src="matsu.png" alt="matsu">
<img id="jesse" src="jesse.png" alt="jesse">
```

And javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#us_select").click(function(){
        $("#sutter,#theo,#holly,#jesse").addClass("us");
        //adds "us" class to the four images. 
    });
    $(".us").click(function(){
        $(this).removeClass("us");
    //removes "us" class from images and thus removing red borders.
    });
});
```

I think `$(".us").click(function()` is the source of my problem. I believe the `$(".us").click(function()` is saying that when I click a html element with the class `us`, all elements with the class `us` are selected and have the `us` class removed. But when I click an image with the `us` class, nothing happens. Any ideas why?

I noticed this code works and is kind of what I'm looking for.

```
$("img").click(function(){
        $(.us).removeClass("us");
    });
```

But this code removes the `us` class when I click any image instead of just images with the class `us`.

Comment: `$(".us")` should be in last line

Comment: Give your target elements either a class or id that you target instead then remove the `.us` class

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This code runs *once*:

```
$(".us").click(function(){
    //...
});
```

and *only once*, when the page loads.  At that time, that selector finds no elements which match that class.  So no click handlers are assigned.

Since the nature of the elements changes dynamically, add the click handler to a higher-level common parent element (or just the `document` itself) and filter by the selector dynamically when clicked.  Something like this:

```
$(document).on("click", ".us", function(){
    //...
});
```

This still adds the click handler once when the page loads, but it adds it to `document`.  Which doesn't change.  Any time `document` handles a `click` event, the (optional) second selector in the argument list is evaluated at that time to filter the source of the event before invoking the handler function.

Answer (score 4):

You have to use [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) as the `us` class is not present on load:

```
$(document).on('click', 'img.us', function() {
   $('.us').removeClass('us');
})
```

In this way, you **delegate** the click event to an element that is present on load (document)

Answer (score 0):

Assign the elements another class like `.off` and then target that class instead.

#### SNIPPET

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#us_select").click(function() {
    $(".off").addClass("us");

  });
  $(".off").click(function() {
    $(this).removeClass("us");

  });
});
```

```css
.us {
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #ff0000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src='http://placehold.it/50x50/000/fff?text=1' class='off'>
<img src='http://placehold.it/50x50/00f/eee?text=2' class='off'>
<img src='http://placehold.it/50x50/0e0/111?text=3' class='off'>
<img src='http://placehold.it/50x50/f00/fff?text=4' class='off'>
<img src='http://placehold.it/50x50/fc0/000?text=5' class='off'>
<img src='http://placehold.it/50x50/fff/000?text=6' class='off'>
<button id="us_select">select American films
</button>
```